# Store credentials with Azure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure, networkcredentials

We need to store credentials to login into a SFTP server for our .Net 4.6 project using MS SQL and Azure, so we are looking for a way to store several credentials to login afterwards. Any advice? We don't want to store the passwords without cipher on a SQL Table.

Comment: Application Settings (App Service) or Azure Key Vault.

Comment: use a securestring in your app settings

Comment: Use Lastpass, that's free tool and secure

Comment: Best way is to use a group account in windows (on both client and server) and add user to windows group.  No password is then needed because it uses the users windows account.  Windows will automatically login to the server using windows credentials which is already encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I checked Azure Key Vault and it sounds good. Specially this example ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/07/02/creating-ftp-data-movement-activity-for-azure-data-factory-pipeline/ ) I think it is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments,  Azure Key Vault should work for you.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/

It is what we recommenced for basically all Azure credential storing.